# Add and remove directives easily

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm looking for a way to dynamically add and remove directives. After digging around I suspect I'll need to use $compile to bind a directive to an element, however I'd like to do this without re-rendering the contents of the element.

I'm attaching the directive to the body tag in the DOM and removing it when no longer required. My directive binds and garbage collects helper methods and observers on elements. Keep in mind that I also have other directives attached to the body, I'll simply be stripping certain directives I no longer need.

Looking for a way to do this without a sub-directive architecture even though I'm considering it as a fallback.

If $compile isn't the correct choice, is there a way to link a directive on an element without effecting it's contents?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$compile` is the right choice, but it's going to be computationally expensive. And you won't be able to remove directives without a lot of manual hacking around things.

What are you actually trying to do? There may be a better, easier solution.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, yah I feared the hacking around things part. I'm simply trying to add a bunch of "support features" into my app that don't really effect the DOM directly. ie. one controls keyboard functions, another supports styling of key elements (but there's different versions of it). Would a controller be a better use case for this? In which case how can I easily add and remove controller? I have one main directive that does the heavy lifting, so I could use a sub-directive-like architecture. :-/

Comment: Just curious, but why do you need to remove it? Can you not just conditionally apply it in the directive?

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the overall memory footprint of the app. It's very intensive and I'd like to turn features on and off neatly with directives.I may be thinking of it incorrectly, but seeing as I can't go in this direction I'll have to take a different approach. Thanks Jeff!

Comment: Perhaps what you want is a service which uses angular.noop for turned off things, and the actual thing for when it's on?